Precise Electronic Measurements
I've been looking into various electronic components and noticed rampant 5%, 10%, and even 20% tolerances and accuracies not only in basic components such as capacitors, inductors, and resistors, but even in thermocouples, thermistors, load cells, etc. That makes me question the accuracy of every single device that I own starting from a body thermometer ending with the kitchen scales. What good is measuring my bodyweight on a scale that even with 1% accuracy will be off by a few pounds? or how do I know when I have fever if a thermometer of similar accuracy is off by several degrees? Can accuracy of 0.1% or better be achieved despite having components such as thermistors with worse than 1% accuracies?

Possibly of interest for Industry Standards - Calibration Standards, Accreditation, and Traceability and What are NIST (National Institute of Standards and Technology) traceable standards?

Tolerance of components isn't directly correlated to the accuracy of the system. The examples you provided include compensation and trimming.

why would you assume there is no means of calibration for error correction or bin control for better tolerances?  PN diode thermometers can be made better than 1% and hospital standards are 0.2'C max error.

why would you require better than 1% accuracy in body weight? ... your weight varies througnout the day

I had a car with a speedometer that read 3MPH over the actual speed, but since I knew I could go a little faster, I wasn't always late to arrive.

You likely own a watch or clock whose tolerance is much better than 0.1%.

@jsotola Picking a random bathroom scale, full scale is 400 lbs. 1% is 4 lbs, for a child, that's 5-10% error.

@user71659 if the scale has repeatable offset and scaling error over its weighing range, it is precise, but not accurate, but could be compensated for. If that error has variation, then the scale isn't precise, let alone accurate.

@dandavis In some jurisdictions at least, it's not legal for a speedo to show any amount under the true speed — but there's no restriction on showing over it, and so to be on the safe side I think manufacturers deliberately design them to read a little high.  (Last time I checked, mine showed around 10% over the true speed.)

The speedometer in each of my 4-wheeled vehicles (2012, 2018) is dead-on accurate, to within 1 mph or so compared to a GPS. My motorcycle (2014)? Not so much, it's consistently, you could even say precisely, 10% high, despite using an all-electronic sensing from ABS and a crystal-accurate microcontroller. Annoying as hell, I wish I could re-flash the thing.

A lot of new cars are actually smart enough to bias the speedometer from the on-board GPS, also saves the manufacturer from dealing with calibration. Europe (UNECE) says no under-read, max overread of 10%+4 km/h. The old North American SAE J678 says either +-4 mph or 4%. There were lawsuits over lease overages and denied warranties, particularly with Japanese cars that overread, so the new SAE J2976 says odometer is +-2.5%, speedometer is -1 to +4%.

You are making some very dubious assumptions. Just because there are resistors with a tolerance of 20% does not mean that more accurate ones aren't available. If a high accuracy resistor is required on some measuring device, it will be used (tolerances as good as 0.01% are readily available). Another example which you noted was thermistors. Indeed low cost thermistors may have tolerances of several degrees. However when needed much better accuracies are available. I personally used, on a sonar application, a thermistor that was guaranteed to within 0.2C over the expected range of seawater temperatures. As pointed out in other answers, instrument accuracy can exceed the tolerance of its internal components when proper calibration and compensation techniques are used

Electronic devices are often calibrated, so that individual component tolerances are compensated for.  With calibration (and maybe temperature compensation) it's often possible to reach accuracies much better than the stated accuracy of the components.
With today's small, cheap and capable microcontrollers it's easy to do multi-point calibration of a thermistor (for example) to get very good accuracy.
In the end, it's the specs required for the system that dictate the component choices and possible calibration required.

A goal of good electronic design is to minimize sensitivity to component variations. That's because precision parts cost more, and even then, don't necessarily hold those tight tolerances over temperature and time.
A quick review of accuracy and precision, here. tl, dr: low variation=high precision, low offset=high accuracy.
If you have a '20%' component that nevertheless doesn't change much (that is, it's stable), then it can be regarded as precise, and can be made accurate by compensating for its offset from ideal.
On the other hand, if that component varies a lot for some reason, it isn't precise, and it will be more difficult to achieve accuracy (may need multiple samples and post-processing to get there.)
Digital calibration methods that use stable, repeatable precise references (e.g., voltage, frequency) are the method of choice now. This adds some circuitry, but saves overall cost by avoiding expensive precision parts and / or manual adjustment.
A load cell in a scale can be characterized for its offset, slope and non-linearity. As long as those don't change much over time, these can be compensated for yielding an accurate and precise measurement. Same thing with thermistors, which are inherently non-linear and need compensation anyway (Steinhart-Hart equation out front should have told ya.)

Some component values in a circuit are not particularly critical so 5%, 10%, and even 20% may be fine. Other components require much better tolerance, and for those precision components are used.
For example a digital thermometer may use 5% resistors in the display portion, but 0.1% resistors in the temperature sensing portion. For really critical uses circuits can use compensation techniques and calibration.
In a television set built in the 1960s almost all of the resistors would be  20% tolerance, that was the standard back then, but they still worked. Your scale and thermometer are pretty accurate as far as you know, right? If  manufacturers were putting out thermometers that were off by a few degrees someone would have noticed by now.

Generally good engineering involves knowing enough to not specify too tight tolerances as well as too loose. You wouldn’t specify bulky $15 ultra-precise metal foil resistors for pull-ups or in series with an LED. Not only would that waste money and space but the product would likely be less reliable because those parts are not made in high volume. A 5% or 1% resistor is more than good enough- on-chip resistors might have 30% or worse tolerance.
Parts that are stable (but not necessarily accurate) can have errors calibrated or compensated out. Clever design can cancel some kinds of errors without external calibration. You can buy resistor networks that have relatively sloppy total resistance but extremely precise ratio and matching of temperature coefficient.
At very tight ratios we might use a custom precision transformer rather than resistors to get ppb (parts per billion) voltage division stability rather than ppm (parts per million) with painfully expensive and difficult to source resistors. Orders of magnitude improvement in accuracy can come at a very high price- it’s not like the digital world where 64 bits is not much more difficult to deal with than 12 bits. Few real-world  analog measurements (other than time) are more accurate than 16-20 bits and most are probably more like 8 to 12. A 1% tolerance NTC thermistor is typically around +/-0.2 ‘C accurate, more than good enough for a consumer product.
Probably the best buried zener monolithic voltage reference in the world has very good stability but the voltage before calibration (using external circuitry such as pricey resistors and such like) may be more than 5% off nominal.
There is far more to precision analog design than merely specifying high performance parts. It’s also certainly possible to design circuits that have excessive sensitivity to component values- where a 0.1% error or drift could cause a 2% error in the measured value. Avoiding calibration may be practical or it may be impossible or just too expensive. All trade-offs that are made during the design process.

What do you mean by using a custom precision transformer instead of resistors? In what scenario can one be used instead of the other?

@beardeadclown Typically in AC calibration or an AC bridge scenario operating in the kHz range, and often in conjunction with a lock-in amplifier in the latter case. Using AC excitation in some circumstances helps get rid of unwanted nV of thermal EMF etc. They can have sub-ppm linearity of set ratio and stability. Most of them sold as instruments have manual switches, this one is GPIB programmable.

While the components themselves may have relatively wide tolerances, it is their final implementation, as well as their RELATIVE change being proportional to the measured values across the measured range.
The rest of the measuring device can be calibrated to compensate for any deviations, and microcontrollers may include precise, accurate and stable reference points, as well as linearity or curve corrections to provide accuracy across a wide range.

Initial tolerance isn't the biggest issue. Equipment requiring precision can be calibrated using trim potentiometers or in software to remove errors. The biggest headache is changes to component parameters over time and temperature. Compared to those, initial values hardly matter at all.
